# How to unit test NGXS async http request?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ngxs

I'm using NGXS in my angular application to manage the state. Now, I'm trying to implement  Unit Tests for NGXS async action. This is what I have implemented so far

**schedule.service.ts**

```
public getSchedulesByOrgIdAndJobRefId(orgId: string, jobRefId: string): Observable<Schedule[]> {
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/schedules';
    return this.httpClient.get<Schedule[]>(url);
  }
```

and action in **schedule.state.ts**

```
@Action(LoadSchedulesAction)
  loadSchedules({patchState, getState}: StateContext<ScheduleStateModel>,
                         {orgId, jobRefId}: LoadSchedulesAction) {
    return this.scheduleService.getSchedulesByOrgIdAndJobRefId(orgId, jobRefId)
      .pipe(
        map((schedules: Schedule[]) => { // convert to a map
          return schedules.reduce((prev: EntityMap<string, Schedule>, curr: Schedule) => {
            prev[curr.id] = curr;
            return prev;
          }, {});
        }),
        tap((schedulesMap: EntityMap<string, Schedule>) => {
          const existingSchedules = getState().schedules;
          patchState({schedules: {...existingSchedules, ...schedulesMap}});
        })
      );
  }
```

This action is working without any issues. When it comes to **Unit testing** there is no documentation or any other article regarding how to test this kind of an **Http async** action.
This is one of my test cases to test that action
**schedule.state.spec.ts**

```
testSchedules = [...Array(5).keys()].map((cd, i: number) => {
      return {
        orgId,
        containerId: `CCD-${i}`,
        jobRefId,
        jobTitle: `Test Job ${i}`,
      };
    });

describe('Actions', () => {
    it('should load and schedules for specific job File', async () => {
      spyOn(scheduleService, 'getSchedulesByOrgIdAndJobRefId')
        .and.returnValue(of(testSchedules));
      await store.dispatch(new LoadSchedulesAction(orgId, jobRefId)).toPromise();
      expect(scheduleService.getSchedulesByOrgIdAndJobRefId).toHaveBeenCalled();
      const scheduleState = store.selectSnapshot((state) => state.schedulesState);
      // using a util method testSchedules converted to a Map type schedulesMap
      expect(scheduleState.schedules).toEqual(schedulesMap);
    });
  });
```

The issue is **scheduleState.schedules** always return en empty object. But if we subscribe to the service call inside **loadSchedules()** function, **scheduleState.schedules** return expected value. But I know we should not subscribe to service call inside en Action implementation

Does anyone know how to Unit Test this kind of action in NGXS?
or am I missing something?

Comment: Consider using a simpler test setup without all those spies and crap until you get the basics of asynchronous testing down.

Answer (score 2):

```
 it('should load and schedules for specific job File', () => {
  spyOn(scheduleService, 'getSchedulesByOrgIdAndJobRefId')
    .and.returnValue(of(testSchedules));
  store.dispatch(new LoadSchedulesAction(orgId, jobRefId)).toPromise();
  expect(scheduleService.getSchedulesByOrgIdAndJobRefId).toHaveBeenCalled();
  const scheduleState = store.selectSnapshot((state) => state.schedulesState);
  expect(scheduleState.schedules).toEqual(schedulesMap);
});
```

You can change the 'it' function as above. You have to inject your scheduleService in BeforeEach section. Also if you want to check your http service url or request Method(POST,PUT or GET) you have to use HttpTestingController which is created for angular http services.